# Unable to pass '<' in URL as parameter

Tags: asp.net, security, webrequest, dangerous-request

Why am I unable to pass '<' character as a parameter in the URL?
If I do:

`http://localhost:9566/?myVar=2`  that is ok

**But I cannot do:**

`http://localhost:9566/?myVar=<foo>` Why does this give me an error?

When I URL-encode `<foo>` I get `%3Cfoo%3E`.

And when I do `http://localhost:9566/?myVar=%3Cfoo%3E`, I still get the same error:

[image]

Comment: Did you read the detailed, helpful message you just posted?

Comment: yeah I don't understand how those atacks work. If I include a space after the '<' character then I don't get the error. For example I could send "< foo >" but I cannot send "<foo>" so I am having a hard time understanding how you could make an attack. I know how to fix it I guess I could replace the '<' with '< ' and then replace it back. it's just that I thought that was a bug and a lot of time there are great answers in here...

Comment: `<script>` is an attack.  This feature block that.

Comment: @hobbs, why does this make asp.net "utterly braindead"?

Comment: @AbeMiessler: Not that I would word it in the same way as hobbs, but this feature assumes that (a) the query param is destined to be displayed on a webpage (a number of param values will never make it to a webpage...) and (b) that the programmer won't sanitize it before putting it on the page. That's actually a bit worrying if this is the only place where such input is sanitized (hopefully not), since escaping should really be done last (when you actually know you're going to display the data): would it not sanitize data from other sources before putting them on a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design.  The characters you are trying to pass could potentially be used in a Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attack.

Here are a few links to get you started on understanding what XSS is:

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29
- http://www.cgisecurity.com/xss-faq.html

While you can disable this type of validation I would not recommend it.  Do you really need to pass a tag in a query string parameter?